# Put values into memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new at xcode and I just built my first app. Basically its a bunch of labels that gets values from a database. The other day my internet wasn't working and didn't realize it and I went to run my app and had empty labels. What I am looking to do is if the variable data is nil then get the values from previously. I think I saw something in tutorials about putting values into memory. Is what I am asking possible? Here is a bit of my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/GetData.php"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSData * data;
}
@end
```

And in your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/GetData.php"];
   data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];
  [self saveToUserDefaults];
    }
```

You can Store it in either DB or in [NSUserDefaults](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/) for saving data in userDefault Use this code

```
- (void)saveToUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"data"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Dilip Data saved");
}
```

And when You want that data back use this code.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults dataForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"Dilip Data : %@",data);
```

Comment: yourData means whatever NSData you have generated from that URL so plz put your NSData value instead of yourData and try again

Comment: `[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"data"];` and `[defaults setObject:url forKey:@"data"];` both give me an error

Comment: what error this code has give `[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"data"];`

Comment: And is your Data is global value, Right? Other wise it will not used in method

Comment: Check my edited answer and do it according.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you're trying to do is called "caching". [Here's a tutorial on how it can be done for images](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/13315-image-caching-tutorial.html).

And if I were to modify your code, I'd write out the data from your server into a file somewhere in "`~/Library/Caches`" and if the server ends up not responding on a subsequent launch, I'd load the previous data from that cache file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You need to store this data to your local. XCode is just a development tool so it will not store the data for you. You have to store your data to some file in document directory. May be using `SQLite` database or a `.plist` file or `NSUserDefaults`.

For SQLIte there are few tutorials:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-creating-and-scripting
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm

you can find more by googleing.

For using .plist
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/07/18/iphone-development-tutorial-create-a-plist-programmatically-after-user-action/

For NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourData forKey:@"data"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

No matter which way you go make sure you delete old values once you receive the new values. If you don't get new values due to any reason you can either try to recorrect by your own or can fetch values from the local store.

I generally prefer `.plist` for temporary use. As you don't need to use the data for long time. Also `NSUserDefaults` is the ios level store and I prefer not to use it on large scale but this is my preference. You can go for either of one.

Hope this helps :)